# Downloading a PDFpage to a string

Tags: android, eclipse, string, pdf, download

Having done some basic tutorials, I started making my first real android app in eclipse. I want this app to check if the text in an EditText matches the text on a PDFpage (this one: http://www.augustinianum.eu/roosterwijzigingen/14062012.pdf (it contains my school's schedule changes)). I've found out how to make the app check if the text in the EditText matches a string (with the method contains()), so now the only thing I need to do is to download all of the text of that PDFpage to a string. But I have no idea how to. Or is there maybe a method which I can check with if a PDFpage contains a certain word without downloading the entire website to a string?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PDF is not a text-file, it is a binary file. Therefore you should not download the data into a string but into a byte array. Then you must extract the text data from the PDF using some PDF library. In **that** text you then can search your keyword.

The most interesting part will be to extract the text from the PDF. You may look around this site for other questions which tried the same. Here is a  [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[pdf]+extract+text&submit=search) or this.

Comment: BTW, this pdf-file is made with a pdf-creator, so you can actually select the text and copy it and stuff. Does that make it easier?

Comment: And you can also search it using CTRL+F

Comment: Do you know if that converting to text uses much juice if it's running in the background every, let's say, hour?

Comment: Once per hour should be OK. BTW: Please be aware, that this site is not a chat site, where one problem leads to the next one. See the FAQ section for this.